# AI: Conditional Independence

Tags: conditional-statements, artificial-intelligence, distribution

[Conditional Independence Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuS0r.png)

[The entire pdf lesson](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~leparker/Courses/CS594-fall04/Lectures/chapter13-14parts.pdf)
it's on page 8.

I've been looking at this for a long time now; can anyone explain how for the P13 we end up with <0.31,0.69>? I'm not sure how the a' gets distributed here. When I calculate 0.2(0.04+0.16+0.16) for the x column I get 0.072, so how do we end up with 0.31?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The α is a normalization constant that is supposed to ensure that you have proper probabilities, i.e. values in [0, 1] that sum to 1. As such, it has to be 1 over the sum of all possible values. For your example, we calculate it as follows.

Let's first evaluate the single expressions in the tuple:

- 0.2 * (0.04 + 0.16 + 0.16) = 0.072
- 0.8 * (0.04 + 0.16) = 0.16

Notice that these two values do not specify a probability distribution (they don't sum to 1).
Therefore, we calculate the normalization constant α as 1 over the sum of these values:

- α = 1 / (0.072 + 0.16) = 4.310345

With this, we *normalize* the original values as follows:

- 0.072 * α = 0.310345
- 0.16 * α = 0.689655

Notice how these values do indeed specify a probability distribution now. (They are in [0, 1] and sum to 1).

I hope this helps :)